# Best Resources for Rails Social Networking Friendship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, social-networking, friend

What do you all think are the best resources for adding a "friendship" system to your rails social networking sites? The main three I have found:

[Self-Referential Associations](http://media.railscasts.com/videos/163_self_referential_association.mov) - Railscast
[acts_as_network](http://github.com/sjlombardo/acts_as_network)
[has_many_friends](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/has_many_friends)

However i find that the railscast one tends to be a bit simplistic, and a lack of implementation documentation for the other two. Can anyone recommend any other plugins or tutorials that might help with the development of this aspect of my social network?

Thanks!

Comment: so which one did you wind up using? any feedback?

Comment: @abbood the railscast one / the accepted answer, though it's been 4 years so I would look at all of them with lots of grains of salt.

Comment: what do you think of [social stream](http://social-stream.dit.upm.es/) @johnnyPando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using restful authentication I would highly recommend this tutorial. It's not the most elegant fleshed out solution, but it will get you on the right path. I was able to copy the code almost verbatim into an app and it works great.

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=16760